# Optimal column type for latitude and longitude on Rails and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, optimization, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I'm wondering what's the best column type to store latitude/longitude on MySQL + Rails.

- Precision must be enough to store every bit of lat/lng degrees obtained from mobile devices and/or geocoders.
- Storage requirement should be minimal for the best query performance.

From Google's official document:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html

> With the current zoom capabilities of
>   Google Maps, you should only need 6
>   digits of precision after the decimal.
>   To keep the storage space required for
>   your table at a minimum, you can
>   specify that the lat and lng
>   attributes are floats of size (10,6).
>   That will let the fields store 6
>   digits after the decimal, plus up to 4
>   digits before the decimal, e.g.
>   -123.456789 degrees.

So, actually `FLOAT(10,6)` is recommended by Google.

However, with Rails 3, there seems no easy way to define `FLOAT` column type with precision after the decimal point. For instance, you could write a migration with raw SQL as follows:

```
def self.up
  execute <<-SQL
  ALTER TABLE places
    ADD `lat` FLOAT(10,6),
    ADD `lng` FLOAT(10,6)
  SQL
  add_index :places, [ :lat, :lng ]
end
```

But the `schema.rb` as a consequence will look like this:

```
t.float "lat", :limit => 10
t.float "lng", :limit => 10
```

which is missing the precision for the fractional part.

Here I can see several options:

- Use `FLOAT(10,6)` for optimal production performance, and don't dump schema (e.g. `rake db:test:load`) on development.
- Use `DECIMAL(10,6)`, which is supported by Rails, but it takes 6 bytes, 1.5 times larger than `FLOAT` (see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html). Maybe this would be a good compromise?
- Use `DOUBLE`, which is much roomier than Google's requirement, and takes 8 bytes, 2 times larger than `FLOAT`. It's simple as well.

What's your recommendation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KISS (i.e. submit to the framework), it's not a lot of bytes. It'll only matter more if you're using particular indexes.

Comment: Yeah, sounds right. It occurs to me that having Sphinx's geospatial index on a separate machine would be nice, as it won't eat memory on the MySQL hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of query you want to do on your data, you might want to look into the geometry type:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/creating-a-spatially-enabled-mysql-database.html

I'm not familiar with RoR, but this line, in particular:

```
add_index :places, [ :lat, :lng ]
```

... seems to indicate that you're planning to run geospatial queries. If so, the index will be useless for all intents and purposes, because a btree index won't help for nearest-neighbor point searches.

Comment: As InnoDB doesn't support geospatial index, I intend to use Sphinx for geospatial queries. But as you indicated, index on (lat, lng) seems like a bad idea whatsoever - I'll research more on geometry type. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, use PostgreSQL. It offers very sophisticated geospatial capabilities in an ACID environment.